# hide jboss server information

Tags: security, jboss, information-hiding

I want to hide jboss server information from any users. (Servlet 2.5; JBoss-
5.0/JBossWeb-2.1, JSF/1.2)

How to do this ?

Comment: in the web.xml , also remnove all files from the root.war

Answer (score 0):

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecureJBoss

Comment: thanks. I cannot find the answer to my question, but I see a lot of useful information about security